# How Does a "face" tend to be defined in Face Recognition Algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

So I am working on implementing YOLOv2 using my own dataset, for face detection. This requires me to prepare a training set of images annotated with the bounding box extents of faces within each image.

My question is: is there any convention for what we define as the face in face detection? For example, do we include the ears? The chin? And if the face is orientated side-on, do we include the ears then?

Or is there no real convention with this?

Thanks for any help you can provide.